Recursive CTE for getting the closing value of previous record as open value in next record
I have two tables as follows:
Table-1: Issue Receipts date wise
werks  matnr  budat    Issue   Receipt
  p1    m1  05-Apr-24   100     40
  p1    m1  29-Apr-24   300     0
  p1    m1  12-May-24   20      450
  p1    m1  21-May-24   308     526
  p1    m1  01-Jun-24   74      289
  p1    m1  15-Jun-24   380     103
  p1    m1  21-Jun-24   411     301
  p1    m1  07-Jul-24   147     0
  p1    m1  13-Jul-24   264     327
  p1    m1  14-Jul-24   465     119
  p2    m2  01-Apr-24   503     550
  p2    m2  08-Apr-24   0       355
  p2    m2  29-Apr-24   238     597
  p2    m2  12-May-24   473     564
  p2    m2  21-May-24   0       539
  p2    m2  15-Jun-24   0       360
  p2    m2  21-Jun-24   487     294
  p2    m2  13-Jul-24   275     0

Table-2: Closing Stock as on 2024-03-31. This will be the Open Stock as on the 1st Transaction date of m1 or m2.
WERKS   MATNR   BUDAT    ClsStock
  p1    m1    31/03/2024    10
  p2    m2    31/03/2024    0

Objective: I want to create a table like below, where closing stock on previous date will be opening stock on the current date.
Closing Stock = Open + Receipts - Issue.
Hence the final table should look like below:
WERKS  MATNR    BUDAT       Open    Issue  Receipts  Close
 p1     m1      05-Apr-24    10     100     40      -50      ---- Please note that open stock it is coming from OpenStock Table
 p1     m1      29-Apr-24   -50     300     0       -350     ---- Closing stock as on 5th April becomes the open stock
 p1     m1      12-May-24   -350    20      450      80
 p1     m1      21-May-24   80      308     526     298
 p1     m1      01-Jun-24   298     74      289     513
 p1     m1      15-Jun-24   513     380     103     236
 p1     m1      21-Jun-24   236     411     301     126
 p1     m1      07-Jul-24   126     147     0       -21
 p1     m1      13-Jul-24   -21     264     327     42
 p1     m1      14-Jul-24   42      465     119     -304
 p2     m2      01-Apr-24   0       503     550     47
 p2     m2      08-Apr-24   47      0       355     402
 p2     m2      29-Apr-24   402     400     300     302
 p2     m2      12-May-24   302     473     250     79
 p2     m2      21-May-24   79      0       539     618
 p2     m2      15-Jun-24   618     0       360     978
 p2     m2      21-Jun-24   978     200     350     1128
 p2     m2      13-Jul-24   1128    275     0       853
 p2     m2      31-Jul-24   853     201     552     1204

With the above requirement, below is the code snippet
---Step 1: We create a temp table that UNION open and issue receipts---
select * into #OpenIssueRece from
(
    select distinct
        ir.matnr
        ,ir.mtart
        ,ir.werks
        ,ir.budat_mkpf
        ,ir.OpenQty
        ,ir.IssueQty
        ,ir.ReceQty
    from #table-1 ir 
    union all 
    select distinct
        o.xmatnr        as matnr
        ,o.mtart        as mtart
        ,o.werk         as werks
        ,o.budat_mkpf   as budat_mkpf
        ,o.OpenQty      as OpenQty 
        ,0              as IssueQty 
        ,0              as ReceQty
    from #Table-2 o
);

--Step 2: Recursive CTE----


with recursive inventorycte(matnr,werks,budat_mkpf,OpenQty, IssueQty, ReceQty, CloseQty,rn) as
(
    select 
        matnr 
        ,werks 
        ,budat_mkpf
        ,cast(Open as numeric(18,2)) as OpenQty
        ,cast(Issue as numeric(18,2)) as IssueQty
        ,cast(Receipts as numeric(18,2)) as ReceQty
        ,cast(Open + Receipts - Issue as numeric(18,2)) as Close
        ,row_number() over(partition by matnr,werks order by budat_mkpf,bwart) rn
       
        from #OpenIssueRece 
        where 
            (matnr,werks,budat_mkpf) in 
                (
                    select matnr,werks,min(budat_mkpf)
                    from #OpenIssueRece
                    group by 1,2
                )


    union all  
    
        select 
            curr.matnr
            ,curr.werks  
            ,curr.budat_mkpf
            ,cast(prev.CloseQty as numeric(18,2)) as OpenQty
            ,curr.IssueQty 
            ,curr.ReceQty
            ,cast(prev.CloseQty + curr.ReceQty - curr.IssueQty as numeric(18,2)) as CloseQty
            ,curr.rn_1 as rn

            from inventorycte prev
            inner join 
                (
                select 
                    matnr 
                    ,werks 
                    ,budat_mkpf
                    ,cast(OpenQty as numeric(18,2)) as OpenQty
                    ,cast(IssueQty as numeric(18,2)) as IssueQty
                    ,cast(ReceQty as numeric(18,2)) as ReceQty
                    ,row_number() over(partition by matnr,werks order by budat_mkpf,bwart) rn_1
                    from #OpenIssueRece
                ) curr 
                on ltrim(curr.matnr,'0') = ltrim(prev.matnr,'0')
                and curr.werks = prev.werks 
                ---and curr.budat_mkpf > prev.budat_mkpf --It is commented. Do we need this? 
                and cast(curr.rn_1 as int) = cast(prev.rn as int)+1
            )
 select 
  matnr
  ,werks 
  ,budat_mkpf 
  ,rn
  ,sum(OpenQty) as OpenQty 
  ,sum(IssueQty) as IssueQty
  ,sum(ReceQty) as RecQty
  ,sum(CloseQty) as CloseQty

  into #finalORIC
  from inventorycte
  group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
  order by matnr, werks,budat_mkpf;

Now the problem statement:
In the table #finalORIC, the issue and receipts qty are getting doubled. Why? Is it because of UNION or any CROSS JOIN is happening?
Please note the above query to be run on Redshift.

I find GROUP BY ordinal position a bit risky. You do group by 1,2,3,4,5,6, but what columns do the numbers represent?

they follow the exact sequences of the columns as written right after the select clause.

So it means matnr, werks, budat_mkpf, rn, sum(OpenQty) as OpenQty, sum(IssueQty) as IssueQty?

Is there more to this that you aren't showing?  This looks to be a straight forward LAG() OVER case.  Recursion looks to be confusing the case.  Would a LAG() solution help?

@Bill: yes lag() can also help here.

See example without recursion.
Direct calculate running total, including opening balance from ClosingStocks.



werks
matnr
budat
Issue
Receipt




p1
m1
2024-04-05
100
40


p1
m1
2024-04-29
300
0


p1
m1
2024-05-12
20
450


p1
m1
2024-05-21
308
526


p1
m1
2024-06-01
74
289


p1
m1
2024-06-15
380
103


p1
m1
2024-06-21
411
301


p1
m1
2024-07-07
147
0


p1
m1
2024-07-13
264
327


p1
m1
2024-07-14
465
119


p2
m2
2024-04-01
503
550


p2
m2
2024-04-08
0
355


p2
m2
2024-04-29
238
597


p2
m2
2024-05-12
473
564


p2
m2
2024-05-21
0
539


p2
m2
2024-06-15
0
360


p2
m2
2024-06-21
487
294


p2
m2
2024-07-13
275
0






WERKS
MATNR
BUDAT
ClsStock




p1
m1
2024-03-31
10


p2
m2
2024-03-31
0



select *
from(-- take opening balance as previous close balance
select werks,matnr,budat
  ,case when lag(tot)over(partition by werks,matnr order by budat) is null
     then Receipt 
  else
     lag(tot)over(partition by werks,matnr order by budat)
  end OpenBalance
  ,Issue,Receipt
  ,tot CloseBalance
  ,bt
from(. -- calculate running total
  select * 
    ,sum(Receipt-Issue)over(partition by werks,matnr order by budat) tot
  from( -- Union IssueReceipts and ClosingStocks
    select 'day' bt,werks,matnr,budat,Issue,Receipt 
    from IssueReceipts
    union all
    select 'open' bt,werks,matnr,budat
       ,case when ClsStock<0 then -ClsStock else 0 end Issue    
       ,case when ClsStock>0 then ClsStock else 0 end Receipt
    from ClosingStocks
   )t1
 )t2
)t3
where bt='day' -- filter only IssueReceipts rows




werks
matnr
budat
OpenBalance
Issue
Receipt
CloseBalance
bt




p1
m1
2024-04-05
10
100
40
-50
day


p1
m1
2024-04-29
-50
300
0
-350
day


p1
m1
2024-05-12
-350
20
450
80
day


p1
m1
2024-05-21
80
308
526
298
day


p1
m1
2024-06-01
298
74
289
513
day


p1
m1
2024-06-15
513
380
103
236
day


p1
m1
2024-06-21
236
411
301
126
day


p1
m1
2024-07-07
126
147
0
-21
day


p1
m1
2024-07-13
-21
264
327
42
day


p1
m1
2024-07-14
42
465
119
-304
day


p2
m2
2024-04-01
0
503
550
47
day


p2
m2
2024-04-08
47
0
355
402
day


p2
m2
2024-04-29
402
238
597
761
day


p2
m2
2024-05-12
761
473
564
852
day


p2
m2
2024-05-21
852
0
539
1391
day


p2
m2
2024-06-15
1391
0
360
1751
day


p2
m2
2024-06-21
1751
487
294
1558
day


p2
m2
2024-07-13
1558
275
0
1283
day



fiddle

I am getting the an error Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause. Essentially I need to mention something like rows unbounded preceding  like this.

Default frame isrows between unbounded preceding and current row. Please, try with this frame.

are you sure? for lag() over does this frame clause work? It is giving error like Frame clause should not be specified for window function lag.

I'm about aggregate sum(..).. For lag() frame not applicable.

So this type of problem is generally not a good use case for recursive CTEs.  There is a depth limit on recursion and unless the chain of calculations can be guaranteed to be less than this into the future you are better off going a different route.
The best way to unroll the calculations by using window functions.  This is much easier to keep straight and faster than recursion.  I'll just post the code here as I think it is straight forward enough but please ask questions if it isn't.
Note that you have a data discrepancy in your source data for 29-Apr-24.  Your definition for table 1 for this data is:

p2    m2  29-Apr-24   238     597

while your expected results has:

p2     m2      29-Apr-24   402     400     300     302

I went with the definition of table 1 so things don't match your expected after this point.
SQL for data setup and query:
create table table_1 (
      werks  varchar(4),
      matnr  varchar(4),
      budat    date,
      Issue   int,
      Receipt int);
insert into table_1 values 
    ('p1', 'm1', '05-Apr-2024', 100, 40),
    ('p1', 'm1', '29-Apr-2024', 300, 0),
    ('p1', 'm1', '12-May-2024', 20, 450),
    ('p1', 'm1', '21-May-2024', 308, 526),
    ('p1', 'm1', '01-Jun-2024', 74, 289),
    ('p1', 'm1', '15-Jun-2024', 380, 103),
    ('p1', 'm1', '21-Jun-2024', 411, 301),
    ('p1', 'm1', '07-Jul-2024', 147, 0),
    ('p1', 'm1', '13-Jul-2024', 264, 327),
    ('p1', 'm1', '14-Jul-2024', 465, 119),
    ('p2', 'm2', '01-Apr-2024', 503, 550),
    ('p2', 'm2', '08-Apr-2024', 0, 355),
    ('p2', 'm2', '29-Apr-2024', 238, 597),
    ('p2', 'm2', '12-May-2024', 473, 564),
    ('p2', 'm2', '21-May-2024', 0, 539),
    ('p2', 'm2', '15-Jun-2024', 0, 360),
    ('p2', 'm2', '21-Jun-2024', 487, 294),
    ('p2', 'm2', '13-Jul-2024', 275, 0);
    
create table table_2 (
      WERKS   varchar(4),
      MATNR   varchar(4),
      BUDAT    date,
      ClsStock int
    );
insert into table_2 values
      ('p1',    'm1',    '2024-03-31',    10),
      ('p2',    'm2',    '2024-03-31',    0);

with dataset as (
      select o.werks, o.matnr, o.budat, 0 Issue, 0 Receipt, ClsStock orig_close
      from Table_2 o
      union all 
      select ir.werks,  ir.matnr,  ir.budat, ir.Issue, ir.Receipt, 0 orig_close
      from table_1 ir
      ),
processed_data as (
      select *,
        sum(issue) over(partition by werks, matnr order by budat rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as sum_issue,
        sum(receipt) over(partition by werks, matnr order by budat rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as sum_receipt,
        sum(orig_close) over(partition by werks, matnr) + sum_receipt - sum_issue new_open, 
        new_open + receipt - issue new_close
      from dataset
)
    select werks, matnr, budat, new_open "Open", Issue, Receipt, new_close "Close"
    from processed_data
    where new_close is not NULL
    order by werks, matnr, budat;

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Revised SQL buffer to reflect the other set of input data.
    drop table if exists table_1;  
drop table if exists table_2;

 create table table_1 (
  werks  varchar(4),
  matnr  varchar(4),
  budat    date,
  Issue   int,
  Receipt int);

  insert into table_1 values 
 ('p1', 'm1', '05-Apr-2024', 100, 40),
 ('p1', 'm1', '29-Apr-2024', 300, 0),
 ('p1', 'm1', '12-May-2024', 20, 450),
 ('p1', 'm1', '21-May-2024', 308, 526),
 ('p1', 'm1', '01-Jun-2024', 74, 289),
 ('p1', 'm1', '15-Jun-2024', 380, 103),
 ('p1', 'm1', '21-Jun-2024', 411, 301),
 ('p1', 'm1', '07-Jul-2024', 147, 0),
 ('p1', 'm1', '13-Jul-2024', 264, 327),
 ('p1', 'm1', '14-Jul-2024', 465, 119),
 ('p2', 'm2', '01-Apr-2024', 503, 550),
 ('p2', 'm2', '08-Apr-2024', 0, 355),
 ('p2', 'm2', '29-Apr-2024', 400, 300),
 ('p2', 'm2', '12-May-2024', 473, 250),
 ('p2', 'm2', '21-May-2024', 0, 539),
 ('p2', 'm2', '15-Jun-2024', 0, 360),
 ('p2', 'm2', '21-Jun-2024', 200, 350),
 ('p2', 'm2', '13-Jul-2024', 275, 0),
 ('p2', 'm2', '31-jul-2024',201, 552);
 
 create table table_2 (
  WERKS   varchar(4),
  MATNR   varchar(4),
  BUDAT    date,
  ClsStock int
 );

 insert into table_2 values
  ('p1',    'm1',    '2024-03-31',    10),
  ('p2',    'm2',    '2024-03-31',    0);

 with dataset as (
  select o.werks, o.matnr, o.budat, 0 Issue, 0  Receipt, ClsStock orig_close
  from Table_2 o
  union all 
  select ir.werks,  ir.matnr,  ir.budat,  ir.Issue, ir.Receipt, 0 orig_close
  from table_1 ir
  ),
 processed_data as (
  select *,
    sum(issue) over(partition by werks, matnr  order by budat rows between unbounded preceding   and 1 preceding) as sum_issue,
    sum(receipt) over(partition by werks, matnr  order by budat rows between unbounded preceding  and 1 preceding) as sum_receipt,
    sum(orig_close) over(partition by werks,  matnr) + sum_receipt - sum_issue new_open, 
    new_open + receipt - issue new_close
  from dataset
)
 select werks, matnr, budat, new_open "Open",  Issue, Receipt, new_close "Close"
 from processed_data 
 where new_close is not NULL
 order by werks, matnr, budat;

p1  m1  2024-04-05  10  100 40  -50
p1  m1  2024-04-29  -50 300 0   -350
p1  m1  2024-05-12  -350    20  450 80
p1  m1  2024-05-21  80  308 526 298
p1  m1  2024-06-01  298 74  289 513
p1  m1  2024-06-15  513 380 103 236
p1  m1  2024-06-21  236 411 301 126
p1  m1  2024-07-07  126 147 0   -21
p1  m1  2024-07-13  -21 264 327 42
p1  m1  2024-07-14  42  465 119 -304
p2  m2  2024-04-01  0   503 550 47
p2  m2  2024-04-08  47  0   355 402
p2  m2  2024-04-29  402 400 300 302
p2  m2  2024-05-12  302 473 250 79
p2  m2  2024-05-21  79  0   539 618
p2  m2  2024-06-15  618 0   360 978
p2  m2  2024-06-21  978 200 350 1128
p2  m2  2024-07-13  1128    275 0   853
p2  m2  2024-07-31  853 201 552 1204


This code is not giving the correct output. Idea is to get the closing qty of previous day as opening qty of current day.

Did you read the answer?  Your source data table and your result data tables don’t match.  If I change the source data (issue and receipts) to match your results values to these columns this query produces the exact results you are looking for.  I’ll update the answer with a revised buffer.

On the actual data too, this is not working. It is correctly computing the close qty. But in cases where openQty >0 there the issue is coming.

My query produced the same result as your expect result (at least to my eye).  I added the query result to my answer. My guess is that you have NULLs in your real dataset.  If there are differences between your source data and what you posted in the question there will be differences.
